# PTIJ: Protection against sukkah being attacked by an eagle?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In Mishna Sukkah 1:3

> ...פֵּרַס עָלֶיהָ סָדִין מִפְּנֵי הַחַמָּה, אוֹ תַּחְתֶּיהָ מִפְּנֵי הַנֶּשֶׁר
>
> If one spread a sheet over the roofing as protection for those sitting in the sukka due to the sun, or if one spread a sheet beneath the roofing as protection due to the eagle...

What is "the eagle"? Was it the same eagle that kept attacking people's סכות?  Did it just keep falling by accident?  Would a sheet really stop an eagle?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: It is the eagle of Moshiach. As it says, we will go back on the wings of eagles to Israel. Since we know that the mitzvah of succah will be given at the time of Moshiach as a test for the nations, it is referring to someone who spreads a sheet to protect his succah from the eagle mistakenly coming in before he’s ready

Comment: *Ah moyradicker kasheh*.

Comment: Actual answer for those who come here after Purim -- the word here means "sheared off", i.e. the s'chach is falling off. My dad says in his childhood memories, it's not Sukkos without pine needles in his soup.

Comment: @Shalom usual translation I have seen is "falling leaves", but נשר does usually refer to an eagle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mamash a good question!

So I've heard the following explanation:

The [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.1.3?ven=Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch,_trans._Rabbi_Avrohom_Davis,_Metsudah_Pub.,_1996&vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi) writes explicitly that the term "קַל כַּנֶּשֶׁר" - "Light as an eagle" is to be understood as:

> כְּנֶגֶד רְאוֹת הָעָיִן
>
> Corresponding to what the eye sees

So likewise here, the reference of an "eagle" is a metaphoric literary device employed to denote seeing the Sechach of the succah.

We know from [Masechta Succah 2a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.2a.8?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that one need to be able to see the sechach. The expression in the Mishnah of, "one spread a sheet beneath the roofing as protection due to the eagle" is to be understood as an expression of one who takes active steps to block that which he can see. In other words, one who unfortunately scoffs at the mitzvah and sadly covers his Sechach to the point where he is no longer able to see it.

We see a similar expression in [Nishmas](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Shabbat%2C_Shacharit%2C_Pesukei_Dezimra%2C_Nishmat_Kol_Chai.1?vhe=Daat_Siddur_Ashkenaz&lang=bi&lookup=%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B5%D7%99&with=Lexicon&lang2=en), where we find again a kofer who shades his eyes from what he can see:

> וְיָדֵינוּ פְרוּשות כְּנִשְׁרֵי שָׁמָיִם
>
> And hands as outspread as eagles of the sky

Whilst it is indeed sad that such individuals take such a grim view of our mitzvos - we can take some solace from the [Prisha on Orach Chaim 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Prisha%2C_Orach_Chaim.1.1.1?vhe=Tur_Orach_Chaim,_Vilna,_1923&lang=bi&lookup=%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%92%D7%AA%D7%9D&with=Lexicon&lang2=en)

> ובקלות כנשר ואל יראה בלעגתם ומפני שא"א שיעמוד בעצימת עינים כל היום
>
> "And lightness like an eagle" - do not fear their mockery because it is impossible to stand with eyes closed all day

So we see from the Prisha that it is our sincere desire that please G-d such people will see the errors of the ways, do teshuva and will re-engage with our holy mitzvos.

Answer (score 4):

True story -- a friend of mine was wearing a shtreimel in the sukkah and an owl entered and began chasing him. I'm sure the owl was thinking -- *six-foot beaver, yum!*. So if the eagle can't see inside, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hashem took us out of Egypt on the wings of eagles. However in the dessert we traveled by the clouds of glory (There are those who learn the clouds actually carried us in the dessert) and they protected us. The Eagles were jealous of the clouds of glory, because they wanted to carry us and protect us all the time in the dessert.The clouds of glory took away their merit of carrying us and protecting us. Therefore the eagles don't like the sukka which is a remembrance for the clouds of glory. As such our Sukkas would need protection against them.

And you can say that the sheet protects us from the eagles, because the mishna says that if you add such a sheet it would pasul the Sukka. A pasul sukka is nothing to be jealous of.