# PTIJ: Why may plaster be used to protect from a vulture's fury?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Chain-PTIJ from this [one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/128404/ptij-protection-against-sukkah-being-attacked-by-an-eagle).

It says in [Mishna Sukkah 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Sukkah.1.3?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Torat_Emet_357&with=all&lang=he):

> "פֶּרֶס עליה- סדין מפני הַחֵמָה"
>
> "If a vulture strikes it, cover it with plaster to protect from its fury".

I suppose plaster strengthens the Sukkah, but doesn't it invalidate it by making it a permanent structure?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: The *peres* is the ossiphrage. Its stomach has incredibly strong acid, and it flies its prey up high and then drops it on a rock to break it apart. Somehow you have to bring that into this.

Comment: סנהדרין לד עמוד ב' ולה עמוד א   א"ר חסדא מניין להוקעה שהיא תלייה דכתיב (שמואל ב כא) והוקענום לה' בגבעת שאול בחיר ה'

דף לה,א גמרא  וכתיב (שמואל ב כא) ותקח רצפה בת איה את השק ותטהו לה אל הצור בתחלת קציר וכתיב (במדבר כה)

Comment: @Shalom Forgot to get back to you, but good find. Sadly, I can't think of any way to insert that into the question. I think anti-acid steel casing is really pushing it...

Answer (score 2):

We know that *ein adam zocheh le'divrei torah elah im kein meimis atzmo alehah* - "One does not merit understanding Torah till he kills himself over it."

Now, between killing yourself as an *am ha'aretz* and the subsequent *techiyas ha'meisim* as a *talmid chacham*, there is a split second when you are dead, and at this moment the *kochos ha'chitzonim*, here represented by a vulture, may "feed on the dead".

This is the anger of the vulture.

Nevertheless plaster may be used to defend ourselves from this, because *ha'adam nivra be'tzelem* - man is created in Hashem's image, and the best thing for making impressions is plaster. So it is the *etzem tzelem elokim* which is never lost which guards a person in the interstices of his *aliyah ruchnis*.

The Succah is the *tzila dimhemnusah* - the shade of faith, and it is this faith that we have in Hashem's eternal protection that causes us to be protected in the above manner.

Answer (score 0):

That's why the mishna says the Sukka is Pasul.

Comment: Which mishna? 15 char.

Comment: The end of that mishna in sukka 1:3 says its pasul.

Comment: You make a good point, but the OP is based on a revowelization of this part of the mishna which sort of negates the ending. At best you could relate the ending to the second part of the sentence.